# What is the limit distance to the base function if offset curve is a function too?

Tags: differential-geometry, functions, plane-curves

I asked a question about parallel functions in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146675/parallel-functions/146708#comment339413_146708) . I understood that offset curves that are the parallels of a function may not be functions after J.M.'s answer. I got new questions after that answer.

Q1) What is the limit distance to the base function if offset curve is a function too?

Q2) It can be shown as geometrically that all [parallel curves](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParallelCurves.html) of line and half circle are also functions. What is the whole function family defination for such functions?

Thanks for answers

Please see parallel curve examples below. (Thanks to [J.M.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/498/j-m) for the graphs) 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I will try to answer question 1 about "limit distance".

For a parametric curve $x=x(t)$, $y=y(t)$ to have an equation of the form $y=g(x)$, we need 
$x$ to be a strictly increasing function of $t$. Suppose we have a smooth function $y=f(x)$ and consider its parallel curve at distance $d$ (measured upward; $d$ could be positive or negative). Then 
$$x(t)=t-d\frac{f'(t)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(t)^2}}$$
If $x'>0$ for all $t$, then the parallel curve is also the graph of a function. Computation shows (after a simplification) that 
$$x'(t)=1-d\frac{f''(t)}{(1+f'(t)^2)^{3/2}}$$
So $x(t)$ is strictly increasing when $$d\frac{f''(t)}{(1+f'(t)^2)^{3/2}}<1$$ and fails to be strictly increasing if the reverse inequality holds. You will find the critical value of $d$ by considering the values of $f''(t)/{(1+f'(t)^2)^{3/2}}$. Not incidentally, the latter quantity is the curvature of the graph $y=f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

A different and somewhat more abstract viewpoint is given by considering the "squared distance function" defined by $\rho(x,y)=d((x,y),G)^2$ for all $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$. Here $G=\{(u,v):v=f(u)\}$ is the graph of your function, considered as a subset of $\Bbb R^2$, and $d((x,y),G)$ is the distance from $(x,y)$ to $G$, which is the same as the distance from $(x,y)$ to the closest point in $G$. (Assume that your function $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$ so that $G$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R^2$.)

If your function $f$ is smooth then $\rho(x,y)$ will be smooth on a neighborhood of $G$. More precisely, if $f$ is smooth of class $C^k$ with $k\geq 2$ then $\rho(x,y)$ will be smooth of class $C^k$ near the graph $G$. (See [this](http://persweb.wabash.edu/facstaff/footer/Papers/RegOfDistFun.pdf).) From now on, we always assume $k\geq 2$. We have used the *squared* distance function to get smoothness *on* the graph $G$, in the same way that the function $x^2$ is smooth at $x=0$ wheras the function $|x|$ is not.

How far away from $G$ will $\rho(x,y)$ be smooth? Let $(x,y)$ be some point in $\Bbb R^2$ and let $(u,v)$ be the point on $G$ which is closest to $(x,y)$ (assume that there is only one such point). If the distance between the two points is less than the [radius of curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature_%28mathematics%29) of $G$ at $(u,v)$ then we are guaranteed that the squared distance function will be smooth at $(x,y)$.

Now compute the radius of curvature $r(u,v)$ of $G$ at a general point $(u,v)$ on the graph $G$. If the radius of curvature is bounded from below on $G$, so that we have $r(u,v)\geq c$ for some $c>0$ and all $(u,v)$ on the graph, then the squared distance will be smooth on the set of points $\{(x,y):d((x,y),G)<c\}$. You can then define parallel graphs on this set as level curves for the distance function $d(\cdot,G)$.

Can something go wrong here? Yes, if there are more than one point on $G$ which is nearest to $(x,y)$. For general curves this can be a problem, but since your curve is the graph of a function this problem cannot occur when $d(x,y)<c$, where $c$ is the uniform lower bound from the last paragraph for the radius of curvature.

I called this approach more abstract, since it is not so easy to get explicit formulas for the distance function $d(\cdot, G)$. Nevertheless, this function (or the function $\rho$) is often a useful tool for studying curves and higher dimensional surfaces.