# Parallel to line on $f(x)=1+\sin(x)/x$

Tags: geometry, plane-curves

I want to draw a curve on the top of the function $f(x)=1+\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$, but the curve should be equidistant (perpendicular distance from any point of the function $f(x)=1+\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$) from every point of the curve. Could anyone help in this regard?

Comment: [It won't necessarily be a function anymore...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146675)

Comment: Yes, that I realized but it is possible to construct that surface numerically. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: You don't need numerics; you should be able to use the formulae [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParallelCurves.html) to derive parametric equations for your parallel curve.

Comment: This general problem is called an "offset curve" and can be based on a curve or polygon.  [This question about bezier offsets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148831/how-to-offset-a-cubic-bezier-curve) may help.

Comment: @Mark, though "parallel curve" is the more standard terminology in the mathematical literature...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've arbitrarily decided to be indulgent today, so I'll write out in full how one might generate the [parallel curve](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParallelCurves.html) of a function. Adapting the formulae from the MathWorld link to the case of a function curve, we have the following parametric equations for a parallel curve to $y=f(x)$ with offset $h$:

$$\begin{align*}
x&=t\pm\frac{h f^\prime(t)}{\sqrt{1+f^\prime(t)^2}}\\
y&=f(t)\mp\frac{h}{\sqrt{1+f^\prime(t)^2}}
\end{align*}$$

For the OP's function, we have, after some simplification,

$$\begin{align*}
x&=t\pm\frac{h (t\cos\,t-\sin\,t)}{\sqrt{t^4+(t\cos\,t-\sin\,t)^2}}\\
y&=1+\frac{\sin\,t}{t}\mp\frac{ht^2}{\sqrt{t^4+(t\cos\,t-\sin\,t)^2}}
\end{align*}$$

Here's a plot of a bunch of parallels, with the starting curve marked in red:

[image: parallel curves for sinc]

As I've previously noted, for certain values of $h$, the curves are no longer functions, and start displaying cusps. On the other hand, even for the parallels that are still functions, it is rather difficult to obtain an explicit $y=f(x)$ expression, so you may have to be content with the parametric representation.

Comment: Thanks a lot J.M. what is the function you have considered in your plot ?

Comment: ...the function you were asking about. What else could it have been?

Comment: The function that I was asking about is not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: Well, since the discontinuity at $0$ is of the *removable* kind, I went ahead and defined the value of the function at $0$ to be the same as the value of an appropriate limit. Or, did you not tackle that limit while learning calculus?