# How can I plot curves relative to other curves?

Tags: functions, plane-curves

Suppose I have a curve – say a sine curve

y=sin(x)

Now I want to draw a second curve, y = ½sin(x), but relative to the first – so it has the first one as a “baseline”. I don’t mean just adding the values (even I can do that!) but as though space itself is curved relative to the first curve...

How impossible is it to come up with a formula to plot this..... ?

[edit] I suppose, what I mean is that at a point x along sin(x) - i.e. distance x measured along the curve, not the x-axis -  draw the normal to the curve, and plot the point on that at distance ½sin(x).

Comment: This sounds more like a math question than a *Mathematica* question…

Comment: Here is one way to warp the space on which a plot is drawn: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24974/1783

Comment: I doubt that this at all impossible, but I feel like you'll have to be more specific about what you mean by "as though space itself is curved relative to the first curve".

Comment: What is different from what you want with plotting $\sin(x)/2 - \sin(x)$ ?  In other words, just subtracting the first curve from all subsequent curves?

Comment: It is a maths question - I thought that's what this place was for. Apologies if not....  once I understand the maths, I can start to write some code...

Comment: oh, oops - sorry!

Comment: Possibly related: [Is “imposing” one function onto another ever used in mathematics?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238534/is-imposing-one-function-onto-another-ever-used-in-mathematics)

Comment: f(x)=f(g^-1(g(x))

Comment: Thank you Andrew D. Hwang - that's exactly what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

You can start by considering [parallel curves](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParallelCurves.html) (a.k.a. "offset curves"), which are curves traced by a normal segment to a curve of a certain length.

Here is the (parametric) formula for a parallel curve to a function $y=f(x)$:

$$\begin{align*}
x&=t\pm\frac{h f^\prime(t)}{\sqrt{1+f^\prime(t)^2}}\\
y&=f(t)\mp\frac{h}{\sqrt{1+f^\prime(t)^2}}
\end{align*}$$

It should be stressed that [parallels are not functions, in general](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146675).

For $y=\sin(x)$, the parametric equations of a general parallel are

$$\begin{align*}
x&=t\pm\frac{h \cos(t)}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2(t)}}\\
y&=\sin(t)\mp\frac{h}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2(t)}}
\end{align*}$$

We then let $h=\sin(t)/2$; that is, a *variable* offset as opposed to a constant offset in the usual case; this yields

$$\begin{align*}
x&=t\pm\frac{\sin(t)\cos(t)}{2\sqrt{1+\cos^2(t)}}\\
y&=\sin(t)\mp\frac{\sin(t)}{2\sqrt{1+\cos^2(t)}}
\end{align*}$$

Here is a plot of $\color{#5e81b5}{\sin(x)}$ and its two offsets:

[image: sin and variable offsets]

Comment: Many thanks for this - interesting, and close to what I want. In fact, I could probably use this ... - but I think Andrew D. Hwang comment to my original post points me exactly where I want.